# Azure HTTP request timeout workaround

Tags: azure, tcp, virtual-machine, windows-server-2008-r2

We currently have an application hosted on a Azure VM instance.

This application sometimes processes long-running and idle HTTP requests. This is causing an issue because **Azure will close all connections that have been idle for longer than a few minutes**.

I've seen some suggestions about setting a lower TCP keepalive rate. I've tried [setting the this rate to around 45 seconds](http://blogs.technet.com/b/nettracer/archive/2010/06/03/things-that-you-may-want-to-know-about-tcp-keepalives.aspx) but my HTTP requests are still being closed.

Any suggestions? Our VM is running Server 2008 R2.

Comment: what is the reference for "Azure will close all connections that have been idle for longer than a few minutes." ?

Comment: @dorin http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cie/archive/2014/02/14/connection-timeout-for-windows-azure-cloud-service-roles-web-worker.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a simple workaround, I had my script send a newline character every 5 seconds or so to keep the connection alive.

Example:

```
set_time_limit(60 * 30);
ini_set("zlib.output_compression", 0);
ini_set("implicit_flush", 1);

function flushBuffers()
{
    @ob_end_flush();
    @ob_flush();
    @flush();
    @ob_start();
}

function azureWorkaround($char = "\n")
{
    echo $char;
    flushBuffers();
}

$html = '';
$employees = getEmployees();
foreach($employee in $employees) {
    html .= getReportHtmlForEmployee($employee);
    azureWorkaround();
}

echo $html;
```

Comment: Can you provide some code to show how you did this?

Comment: Updated with example.

Answer (score 1):

The Azure Load Balancer now supports configurable TCP Idle timeout **for your Cloud Services and Virtual Machines**. This feature can be configured using the Service Management API, PowerShell or the service model.

For more information check the announcement at http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/08/14/new-configurable-idle-timeout-for-azure-load-balancer/

Comment: how to find where my `wcf` hosted in azure? (Cloud Services or Virtual Machines)

Comment: Can i configure tcp idle timeout for app services(i hosted wcf inside my webapp which uses appservices)?