# Azure Web Apps 500 - The request timed out in 4 minutes

Tags: azure, timeout, azure-web-app-service

We have sitecore CMS (asp.net application) hosted in Azure Web Apps. On web.config the excutiontime has been set to 1 hour and the session and form auth is set to expire in 20minutes.

When I try to install the sitecore update package I keep getting error below within 4 minutes.

```
<html><head><title>500 - The request timed out.</title></head><body>  <font color ="#aa0000">         <h2>500 - The request timed out.</h2></font>  The web server failed to respond within the specified time.</body></html>
```

Appreciate if you could help me understand if there any explicit timeout setting on web app that that overwrite my web.config settings? If yes, how do we increase?

I had a look at few thread posts but didn't help:

[Azure Web App or App Service: Service calls(web server) times out after nearly 4mins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40137069/azure-web-app-or-app-service-service-callsweb-server-times-out-after-nearly-4)

[How To Prevent HttpWebRequest with long response from timing-out Azure Web App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30541531/how-to-prevent-httpwebrequest-with-long-response-from-timing-out-azure-web-app)

Thanks.

Comment: See this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38673318/azure-asp-net-webapp-the-request-timed-out/38676086#38676086

Comment: Unfortunately can't change the package installation logic (no access to source code for CMS)